# GetBucketLocation - Acces Denied

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3

I have a lambda that I need to write that requires the bucket location for a given `S3` bucket. I've set the permission to allow `GetBucketLocation` on all `S3` buckets but I still get the following error:

```
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the GetBucketLocation operation: Access Denied
```

I have even attached admin role rights to the function and I still get the above message. Is there any way to have `GetBucketLocation` to work?

For completeness the function looks as following:

```
# Libraries
# Standard Libaries
import json
import time
import urllib

# Third Party Libraries
import boto3


CLOUDFRONT_CLIENT = boto3.client('cloudfront')
S3_CLIENT = boto3.client('s3')


def get_cloudfront_distribution_id(bucket):
    bucket_location = S3_CLIENT.get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket) # <<<--- THIS PART FAILS
    bucket_origin = f'{bucket}.s3.{bucket_location}.amazonaws.com'
    cf_distro_id = None

    # Create a reusable Paginator
    paginator = CLOUDFRONT_CLIENT.get_paginator('list_distributions')

    page_iterator = paginator.paginate()

    ...

    return cf_distro_id


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    '''
    Creates a cloudfront invalidation for content added to a S3 bucket
    '''
    # Get the object from the event.
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'])

    if not key.startswith('/'):
        key = f'/{key}'
 
    cf_distro_id = get_cloudfront_distribution_id(bucket)
    ...
```

The `IAM` role

```
  #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
  # Roles                                                               #
  #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
  LambdaRole:
    Description: IAM role to allow Lambda to invalidates content in a cloudfront distro when S3 content changes
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action: sts:AssumeRole
          Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service:
            - lambda.amazonaws.com
          Sid: 1
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - !Sub arn:${AWS::Partition}:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
      RoleName: !Join
        - '-'
        - - !Ref AWS::StackName
          - Role
```

The `IAM` Policy

```
  #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
  # Policies                                                            #
  #~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#
  LambdaPolicy:
    Description: Setting IAM policy for service role for Lambda to invalidate cloudfront S3 cache
    Type: AWS::IAM::Policy
    Properties:
      PolicyDocument:
        Statement:
        - Action:
          - s3:GetObject
          - s3:GetObjectVersion
          - s3:GetBucketVersioning
          - s3:PutObject
          Effect: Allow
          Resource:
          - !Sub 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:s3:::${ArtifactsBucket}'
          - !Sub 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:s3:::${ArtifactsBucket}/*'
        - Action:
          - logs:CreateLogGroup
          - logs:CreateLogStream
          - logs:DeleteLogGroup
          - logs:DeleteLogStream
          - logs:PutLogEvents
          Effect: Allow
          Resource:
          - !Sub 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:logs:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:*'
        - Action:
          - cloudfront:CreateInvalidation
          - cloudfront:GetDistribution
          - cloudfront:GetStreamingDistribution
          - cloudfront:GetDistributionConfig
          - cloudfront:GetInvalidation
          - cloudfront:ListInvalidations
          - cloudfront:ListStreamingDistributions
          - cloudfront:ListDistributions
          Effect: Allow
          Resource: '*'
        - Action:
          - s3:GetBucketLocation
          - s3:ListBucket
          Effect: Allow
          Resource:
          - !Sub 'arn:${AWS::Partition}:s3:::*'
      PolicyName: !Join
        - '-'
        - - !Ref AWS::StackName
          - LambdaPolicy
      Roles:
      - !Ref LambdaRole
```

The generated policy found in `IAM`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "cloudfront:GetDistribution",
                "cloudfront:GetStreamingDistribution",
                "cloudfront:ListInvalidations",
                "cloudfront:ListDistributions",
                "cloudfront:GetInvalidation",
                "cloudfront:ListStreamingDistributions",
                "cloudfront:GetDistributionConfig",
                "cloudfront:CreateInvalidation"
            ],
            "Resource": "*"
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "logs:CreateLogStream",
                "logs:DeleteLogGroup",
                "s3:GetBucketVersioning",
                "logs:CreateLogGroup",
                "logs:DeleteLogStream",
                "logs:PutLogEvents",
                "s3:GetObjectVersion"
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:logs:us-east-1:123456789000:*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::123456789000-util-invalidate-cloudfront-artifactsbucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::123456789000-util-invalidate-cloudfront-artifactsbucket"
            ]
        },
        {
            "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:GetBucketLocation"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the IAM policy?

Comment: When your template is deployed, take a look at the IAM Role that is created, and the IAM Policies that are attached. Do you see the `s3:GetBucketLocation` permission attached? Can you show us the JSON policy that is created?